# Error handling in perl api

Tags: perl, api, data-mining

I am trying to extract data from website using Perl API. I am using a list of URIs to get the data from the website.

Initially the problem was that if there was no data available for the URI it would die and I wanted it to skip that particular URI and go to the next available URI. I used `next unless ....;` to come over this problem.

Now the problem is I am trying to extract specific data from the web by calling a specific method (called as identifiers()) from the API. Now the data is available for the URI but the specific data (the identifiers), what I am looking for, is not available and it dies.

I tried to use eval{} like this

```
eval {
    for $bar ($foo->identifiers()){
        #do something
    };
}
```

When I use eval{} I think it skips the error and moves ahead but I am not sure. Because the error it gives is "Invalid content type in response:text/plain".

Whereas I checked the URI manually, though it doesn't have the identifiers it has rest of the data. I want this to skip and move to next URI. How can I do that?

I got a reply from one of the experts that:
*When Perl hits an error, like most languages, it runs out through the calling contexts in order until it finds a place where it can handle the error. Perl's most basic error handling is eval{} (but I'd use Try::Tiny if you can, as it is then clearer that you're doing error handling instead of some of the other strange things eval can do).
Anyway, when Perl hits eval{}, the whole of eval{} exits, and $& is set to the error. So, having the eval{} outside the loop means errors will leave the loop. If you put the eval{} inside the loop, when an error occurs, eval{} will exit, but you will carry on to the next iteration. It's that simple.*

But really the error  I get is invalid content type in response: text/html at mycode line 41 and the line 41 in my code (my program) is really to the data from web. I know there is no error in the code because it works fine for previous uris. Now, how do I fix this error and move ahead to next uri? my program stucks at this error.

Comment: Note based on other discussion under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693259/skipping-error-in-eval-statement/6693416#6693416: this isn't using LWP::UserAgent directly, but Connotea Perl API, which only accepts XML content types. The error above is from Connotea Perl, not LWP::UserAgent

Comment: @morungos. Thank you for your reply and I am sorry for repeating this question twice I am getting familiar to stackoverflow. Well, I was playing around a bit line of my code to get the tags. I used eval around that line of my code which is to get the tags. What it means to use the eval literally around the whole of the code? Can you please elaborate this. Thank you Sammed

Comment: Suggest editing the code in the question to show a little more context, not much we can do as it stands

Comment: @morungos. Well, I didn't get you. Do you mean to post the code. Here is the snippet of code I am using and where it stucks `while (<IN0>)
{  my $currentURI = $_;
    chomp($currentURI);
    my @tags = $c->posts_for(uri =>"$currentURI");` and I get error for this my @tags line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm now assuming your code looks something like this:

```
while (<IN0>) {
    my $currentURI = $_; 
    chomp($currentURI); 
    my @tags = $c->posts_for(uri =>"$currentURI");
    ... do something ...
}
```

To handle errors, safely, use something like this (assuming `eval()`):

```
while (<IN0>) {
    my $currentURI = $_; 
    chomp($currentURI); 
    my @tags = eval {        # Use eval to make this safe, $@ will contain any error
        $c->posts_for(uri =>"$currentURI");
    }
    my $error = $@;
    if (defined($error)) {
        warn($error);        # If eval failed, warn and skip to next line
        next;
    }
    if (! @tags) {
        next;                # Assuming no tags means go to next line in input
    }
    ... do something ...
}
```

All `eval` really does here is guarantee that Perl errors which can be handled leave the `eval` block in the normal way, although if that happens, `@tags` will be empty, and `$@` will contain the error. The remaining logic warns (and skips the input line) if `$@` was set. You likely want to skip the line anyway if there are no tags.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It worked and I really appreciate your help and precious time. This has also helped me to learn error handling. Thank you a lot. You are a savior for me. Thank you. :)

Comment: It seems that you must put a semi-colon after the second curly-brace of eval{}; according to perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html - is that correct?